# Detect which View was tapped in the onSingleTapConfirmed method

Tags: android, view, gesture

I have many views (FrameLayouts) on my screen - each has a SimpleOnGestureListener set as the onTouchListener.

I'm correctly getting the onSingleTapConfirmed method being fired when I tap one of these views, but I can't work out how to determine which view was tapped?

Is there a simple way to do this from the MotionEvent?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

> I have many views (FrameLayouts) on my screen - each has a SimpleOnGestureListener set as the onTouchListener.

Save a reference to the View in the OnTouchListener, then when a gesture callback fires you'll already know which View was touched:

```
public boolean onTouch(View v, MotionEvent event) {
    // Remember which View was touched
    mCurrent = v; 

    // Pass event to gesture listener, etc
}
```

Now use `mCurrent` in `onSingleTapConfirmed()` and any other method.

Comment: Duh...  That'll teach me to copy and paste code without reading it - hadn't seen that I have the View in the onTouch event... Thanks